# Error: Failed to parse wsdl: targetNamespace not specified in wsdl:definitions

Tags: integration, soap, wsdl

The wsdl I am parsing is throwing the above mentioned error .

The wsdl starts like below and has targetNamespace populated :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
 <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
  targetNamespace="urn:telco.com/us/pps/service/UpdateHistoryWSV1.0"
```

What could be the reason? Do I need to make any changes in the wsdl manually?

Comment: Do you have any other schema under this wsdl? Search for 'schema' in the wsdl and see if all of them has a targetnamespace specified there.

Comment: Can you share the WSDL in question?